# Get view machine name programmatically

Tags: views

I am using a code

```
<?php
print $view->display['view_machine_name']->handler->options['title'];
?>
```

I put machine name in view_machine_name and everything work but I have few displays with different machine names and in other cases I still print same title. Can I get a function which takes the view machine name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [views_get_page_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_page_view/7) function, Which return Views object and you can get current views name on  `$views_page->name`

Comment: I displayed title using:
$title = $view->get_title();  print $title;
Thank you for help.

Comment: And in drupal 8? in lets say the hook_preprocess_page function?